# PHP cURL "Could not resolve host: maps.googleapis.com; Unknown error"

Tags: php, curl

I realize this is a question that has been asked several times before, but I have tried the given answers, I feel, up and down and feel like I'm banging my head against a wall.

PHP/cURL:

```
$this->ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  2);

curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1956+Mountain+View+Drive,+San+Diego,+CA&key=?????");
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");

$response = curl_exec($this->ch);

var_dump($response);
var_dump(curl_error($this->ch)); die;
```

As is, I get "Could not resolve host: maps.googleapis.com; Unknown error". If I add this:

```
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 )
```

Which was suggested in another post, the error changes to: "Could not resolve host: maps.googleapis.com; Name or service not known"

Either way, I can't seem to find a way to not get an error. I can put the URL into the web browser and it geocodes fine for me. We have plenty of other API integrations that use a similar setup with cURL and work fine, so I don't feel like it's a general server-wide issue, but that it's specific to this use case.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post links to questions where you have tried answers? It could either inspire somebody to give a new answer that works for you, or inform others what has not worked for you.

Comment: All the stackoverflow issues that centered around a problem like this were either (1) server related (which I believe my issue is limited to this use case) or (2) centers around turning off verifypeer, adding verifyhost and setting it to 2, or changing the curl_ipresolve to version 4. My above code tries to attack all those issues and things still won't work via cURL (though they do when I type the request URL straight up in my browser window)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you created your Geocoding API before proceeding?
if not go to http://console.developers.google.com > APIs & auth > APIs > under Google Maps APIs press more > Geocoding API > enable the api and get your key
so the code will be like

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  2);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1956+Mountain+View+Drive,+San+Diego,+CA&key=YOUR_KEY_HERE");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");

$response = curl_exec($ch);

print "<pre>";
var_dump($response);
var_dump(curl_error($ch)); die;
```

if the above did not work then you may have a problem in the curl library i assume,

else than that since you are only requesting get data you can simply use

> file_get_contents()

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1956+Mountain+View+Drive,+San+Diego,+CA&key=YOUR_KEY");
```

then it will output

```
{ "results" : [ { "address_components" : [ { "long_name" : "1956", "short_name" : "1956", "types" : [ "street_number" ] }, { "long_name" : "North Mountain View Drive", "short_name" : "N Mountain View Dr",...
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Yes I have created the key. I can put the whole request into the browser and it geocodes great for me. But when I try to run it through cURL that's when I get the trouble resolving host issue.

Comment: It does indeed. Screw cURL. Thanks!